# Cannot compile branch.io on Android Studio, Gradle build error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, branch.io

Cannot compile branch.io on Android, Gradle build error

with the message

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6

Last time its has no errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change 
from

```
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
```

or

```
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.1'
```

**to**

```
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.2'
```

Because they remove version 1.14.1

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/releases

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: yes, we accidentally pushed out a bad 1.14.1 release yesterday and withdrew it. Updating as suggested here *should* resolve the issue...let me know if it does not

Comment: I changed version from 2+ to 2.19.3. Now it works. Thanks